# c# parse a string that contains conditions , key=value

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing, formatting

I m giving a string that contains several different combination of data.

For example :

string data = "(age=20&gender=male) or (city=newyork)"
string data1 = "(job=engineer&gender=female)"
string data2 = "(foo =1 or foo = 2) & (bar =1)"

I need to parse this string and create structure out of it and i have to evaluate this to a condition of another object. eg: if the object has these properties, then do something , else skip etc.

What are the best practices to do this?

Should i use a parser such as antlr and generate tokens out of the string. etc.?

reminder : there are several combinations of how this string is created. but it s all and/or.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like ANTLR is probably overkill for this.

A simple implementation of the [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) would probably do the trick quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Using *regular expressions* may work if the example is very simple, but it will more likely lead to a code that is impossible to maintain. Using some other approach to parsing seems like a good idea.

- I would take a look at [NCalc](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ncalc) - it is mainly focused on parsing mathematical expressions, but it seems to be quite customizable (you can specify your functions and constants), so it may work in your scenario as well.
- If this is too complex for your purpose, you can use any "parser generator" for C#. Using ANTLR is one great option - here is an example that shows how to start writing something like your example [Five minute introduction to ANTLR](https://web.archive.org/web/20100927065748/http://www.antlr.org:80/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Five%20minute%20introduction%20to%20ANTLR%203)
- You could also try using F#, which is a great language for this kind of problem. See for example [FsLex Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/chrsmith/fslex-sample) by Chris Smith, which shows a simple mathematical evaluator - processing the parsed expression in F# would be a lot easier than in C#. In F#, you could also use [FParsec](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/&rct=j&q=f#%20parser%20combinators&ei=CMsoTKfVAsqJOJGMmKMC&usg=AFQjCNGhe2csZzACEltKpGwPUSU0Nbllsg&sig2=9w6St3q4EhXjQV_wxA14kQ), which is very lightweight, but may be a bit difficult to follow if you're not used to F#.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might want to use Regular Expressions to do this.

Read up a little bit on Regular Expressions in .NET.  Here are some good articles:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

When it comes time to write/test your Regular expression i would highly recommend using RegExLib.com's [regex tester](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look at regular expressions: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Antlr is a great tool, but you can probably do this with regular expressions. One of the nice things about the .NET regex engine is support for nested constructs. See

http://retkomma.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/nested-regular-expressions-explained/

and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns).